# SonarQube background tasks failing for C#

Tags: c#, sonarqube, sonar-runner

Since upgrading to SonarQube 5.2, and the to the C# analyzer version 4.3, all of the background tasks have been failing. The analysis succeeds, but when processing the batch, sonarqube throws this error:

```
2015.11.25 15:29:50 ERROR [o.s.s.c.t.CeWorkerRunnableImpl] Failed to execute task AVFA-0Hf0RdTwH4buniL
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Multiple entries with same key: cs=C# and cs=C#
```

Here is the complete log:
http://pastebin.com/YNTQey2F

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figured this out. Of course, in hind sight the error made perfect sense. We had been exploring using an additional analyzer from Coverity, and I had added their plugin, which created an additional Quality Profile for C#. I deleted that profile and the problem was fixed.

TL;DR Confirm that you have a default Quality Profile set, and your project is referencing it.